# Website error for HTTPS; But website works fine through HTTP

Tags: https, hosting, cpanel, web-deployment, web-hosting

I just installed a SSL certificate on the website and confirmed that it was set-up correctly. But for some reason when visiting the website through HTTPS it gives the error "Not Authorized to View This Page [CFN #0004]". But HTTP works fine.

It's a WordPress website and the htaccess file has not been modified.

What could be the problem?
[www.benchmarkadvertising.ca](http://www.benchmarkadvertising.ca) https://benchmarkadvertising.ca/

I've Googled and Googled but cannot find a solution. Called my hosting company, but they're not specialized enough to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First off check this may be a plugin or theme conflict. Please attempt to disable all plugins, and use one of the default (Twenty*) themes. If the problem goes away, enable them one by one to identify the source of your troubles.

If you can install plugins, install “Health Check”: https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/ On the troubleshooting tab, you can click the button to disable all plugins and change the theme for you, while you’re still logged in, without affecting normal visitors to your site.

Comment: Hi I tried all of that. I don't think it's a problem with WordPress. The website works fine. It just doesn't work for HTTPS.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a plugin serving the site over HTTP making the site insecure? You have to do a thorough debug

Comment: I disabled all plugins and I still get the same error. I also tried a default theme.

Comment: Did you try the default theme while all the plugins are disabled??